# I've powered off and on my Ubuntu instance on Scaleway and now ping or SSH timeout

Tags: ssh, cloud, timeout, hosting

I used to connect through SSH into the instance and do my thing.

They needed to update the private IP of the instances and I had to just turn off and on the instance in order for that to happen.

Once I did that, I couldn't SSH anymore - it just hang until I received a timeout. Pinging the instance using the IP also timeouts.

They have a "rescue" boot image and I'm able to boot and mount the volume myself in order to investigate, but I don't know what to look at or what to do to make the instance be able to boot normally and work.

There wasn't anything fancy in there, just a mongo DB, a small node application, and a Let's Encrypt Certificate.

Details:

`> uname -a`

`Linux ... 4.4.127-mainline-rev1 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 10:38:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Reminder: Community Support for Ubuntu 16.04 will end soon in April 2021. This might be a good opportunity to back up your data and migrate to a newer release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the solution was a simple and stupid one.

Instead of "Use local boot" (considered normal mode, as it was and worked until this issue happened), I chose "Use bootscript" and picked "x86_64 mainline latest".

[image: Selected option in the control panel]